# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8088/web/webclient/version_info error in ionic login to odoo server

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, odoo

When I trying to login with ionic app to odoo server. I got below quoted error. if it is because of CORS, how can I config in local odoo server without using nginx?

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8088/web/webclient/version_info. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Comment: try to use a plugin called [whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add cordova whitelist plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Make prepare

```
cordova prepare
```

Add below lines into config.xml

```
 <access origin="*"/>

  <allow-intent href="*"/>

  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

For the CORS for browser, open chrome by cmd or terminal.

For windows,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-agent="Android" --user-data-dir="C:/temp-chrome-eng
```

For mac-osx,

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/Users/thantshweaung/Documents/Project/ionic/chrome_cache"
```

Solved!

Answer (score 1):

By Default browsers are made to block the request for cross domain due to security reasons but we can acheive cross origin request working by following ways.

Open Chrome and install this plugin and on it, then try to send request it will work, But its not a good idea.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Second Idea

The best thing is to go to your middleware and add headers as

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

it will allow all request from different domain.

Comment: I already installed plugin and also config header as you recommend already. But still error.

Comment: once install check CORS button on chrome is showing green then only it will work try restarting it.

Comment: and in which language you are writing your server side code if it is nodejs then you can add these stuffs

Comment: res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

Comment: Odoo ERP bro. That ERP system use python language. Thanks

Comment: If you liked the answer please tick on left side of the screen near up-down arrow Thanks

Comment: Still try to solve error. Thanks. After that I will.

Comment: @HemantNagarkoti I have added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in response my client and server is running in different port . still got the below error is there any other configuration i need to add

Comment: make sure have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin in server for exaemple res.setHeaders('Access-Control.....')  not at client side

Comment: i am using express, how to add ?

Answer (score 1):

For Node Js

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your IP address instead of `localhost`. For example:

```
http://192._._._:8088/web/webclient/version_info
```

Comment: Actually I used IP address. Thanks.